# different div transition/show when hovering over left or right side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if anyone has an example to have a div that is hovered on the left side to show divone divtwo divthree and divfour, however when hovered on the right show divfive divsix divseven and diveight instead. I'd like it to look like this when either side is hovered over: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCnQl.png

But, right side and left side should show different contents. When neither side is being hovered over, show nothing.

Also, here's the catch... The divs have to be repeatable, and will share unique names multiple times on the page, as this is for an account informational panel. there can be up to 10 on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML - wrapper div has unique name. Child divs have a right or left class name

```
<div id="containerOne">
<div class="left" style="display:none;">Left Side 1</div>
<div class="left" style="display:none;">Left Side 2</div>
<div class="left" style="display:none;">Left Side 3</div>
<div class="right" style="display:none;">Right Side 1</div>
<div class="right" style="display:none;">Right Side 2</div>
<div class="right" style="display:none;">Right Side 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS - Wrapper div appears as box, child divs styles float, or could just right and align text in 100% div width

```
#containerOne {
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
width: 250px; 
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #333;
}
.left{
float:left;
width:100%;
text-align:left;
}

.right{
float:right;
width:100%;
text-align:right;
}
```

script to determine which side this mouse is one, and then set style based on which side mouse is on, on mouse leave display = none for all child divs

```
function UpdateStyle(cls, style){
var left_ele = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for (var i = 0; i < left_ele.length; ++i) {
            var item = left_ele[i];  
            item.style.display = style;
        }   
}
$("#containerOne").on('mousemove', function(e) {
var mouseSide;
if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
    UpdateStyle('left','block');
     UpdateStyle('right','none');
} else {
       UpdateStyle('left','none');
     UpdateStyle('right','block');
}
}).on('mouseout', function(){
 UpdateStyle('left','none');
     UpdateStyle('right','none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/w94L9/)**

It is not exactly what you are looking for but you can get based on this to customize it and achieve what you need.

I am using the jQuery

```
$("#selector").on(
{
    mouseenter: function() 
    {
        $("#toggle").show('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $("#toggle").hide('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps